# PHPhotoLibrary - photoLibraryDidChange called multiple times in Swift

Tags: swift, photosframework, phphotolibrary

I have the following code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    ........
    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().register(self)
}
```

and I've implemented the `PHPhotoLibraryDidChangeObserver`.

My problem is, that the method `photoLibraryDidChange` gets called multiple times if something in the device's gallery changes.
Here is the code for that function:

```
func photoLibraryDidChange(_ changeInstance: PHChange) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        self.updateFetchResult();
    })
}
```

Do you know why this method gets executed `multiple` times?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I just implemented the `PHPhotoLibraryChangeObserver` protocol and tested it by taking a screenshot while looking at my `UICollectionView`. I noticed that `photoLibraryDidChange(_ changeInstance: PHChange)` is called twice when I take a screenshot.

Comment: also looking for a answer for that. In my code the photoLibraryDidChange is called about 3 times. But most times only with no actual changes

Answer (score 0):

Did you find a solution?
This solve mi problem:

First, save your `PHFetResult<PHAsset>` when calling `PHAsset.fetchAssets(with:options:)` if your using this method.

After that, use your `PHFetResult<PHAsset>` variable to validate if the fetch result has changes in the `photoLibraryDidChange:` method. The first time this method is called, you have to update to collection view or table view. After that, your fetch result has not changes so... you have nothing to update.

This is my full code:

```
let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]

self.fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions)

.
.
.

extension YourViewController: PHPhotoLibraryChangeObserver {

    func photoLibraryDidChange(_ changeInstance: PHChange) {
        if let _fetchResult = self.fetchResult, let _ = changeInstance.changeDetails(for: _fetchResult) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.getPhotos()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Hope this help you!

Answer (score 0):

```
extension YourViewController: PHPhotoLibraryChangeObserver {

    func photoLibraryDidChange(_ changeInstance: PHChange) {
        if let _fetchResult = self.fetchResult, let resultDetailChanges = changeInstance.changeDetails(for: _fetchResult) {
            let addedItems = resultDetailChanges.insertedObjects
            let deletedItems = resultDetailChanges.removedObjects
            let changedItems = resultDetailChanges.changedObjects
            if resultDetailChanges.hasIncrementalChanges && (addedItems.count > 0 || deletedItems.count > 0 || changedItems.count > 0){
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.getPhotos()
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Above check of `resultDetailChanges.hasIncrementalChanges` and counts of (added, removed, changed assets) will protect to avoid multiple calls.

Comment: Still called twice for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
extension YourViewController: PHPhotoLibraryChangeObserver {

        func photoLibraryDidChange(_ changeInstance: PHChange) {
            if let _fetchResult = self.fetchResult, let resultDetailChanges = changeInstance.changeDetails(for: _fetchResult) {
                let insertedObjects = resultDetailChanges.insertedObjects
                let removedObjects = resultDetailChanges.removedObjects
                let changedObjects = resultDetailChanges.changedObjects.filter( {
                    return changeInstance.changeDetails(for: $0)?.assetContentChanged == true
                })
                if resultDetailChanges.hasIncrementalChanges && (insertedObjects.count > 0 || removedObjects.count > 0 || changedObjects.count > 0){
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.getPhotos()
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do it now you should add 2 row

```
let hasInsertionFromUser = changeInstance.changeDetails(for: resultDetailChanges.fetchResultAfterChanges) != nil
let hasAcessGrantedByUser = changeInstance.changeDetails(for: resultDetailChanges.fetchResultBeforeChanges) != nil
```

Otherwise, upon access, the method initially does not work and when adding new photos from the gallery, with picking concrete photo too.

Answer (score 0):

Personal summary and guesses:
Usually it is called twice, once when the number of photos in the album library changes, and once when the number of photos in a single album changes.
After I turn on the iCloud function, it is three times, because I will also be notified once when deleting or uploading from iCloud.
If you want to avoid multiple calls, you need to first get the PHFetchResult in the photo album library, and then use changeInstance.changeDetails(for: fetchResult) in this method to know whether it has changed before or after.